# Please help me find the brand of bike on the pictures

Tags: identify-this-bike, citi-bike, movie

Saw him in the movie "Greta", but I can't recognise what brand it is([image: thanks]

Comment: \*shrug\* It's a bike. Single-speed/fixie flip-flop hub. It's probably had the stickers taken off. Unlikely that any ID will be possible without a clear photo of the whole bike.

Comment: Your other options are to make contact with the movie company, or publicity company for the film, and get some information there.  Some companies go out of their way to make trivia available for IMDB etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**answer**  no idea.

However we can tell its a road bike, that has dual pivot caliper rim brakes front and rear.

It also has a flip-flop hub on the rear wheel because we can see a cog on the left hand side of the bike.   There are no shifters visible, so we can safely assume its a fixed gear and single speed bike with a chain-drive transmission.

The wheels both show spoke reflectors, which suggest its a newish bike and the plastic has not embrittled and snapped with UV light.  They have Presta valves visible on the front wheel, and are slightly aero wheels, not old-school box section rims.

Up top there's a bullhorn handlebar, which is trendy with the fixie crowd.  It does not look like a flop-and-chop drop bar because of the slight angle up instead of a curve up.

The frame has externally routed cables.  Whats  somewhat unusual is that the rear brake cable is held on with two visible clamping bands (probably 3 in reality)   This is not common on recent frames who would normally use two braze-on cable stops and leave the inner wire exposed.

Generally - the frame could be anything from 1990 to current.  I'd guess its not 1980s frame because they normally had much longer head tubes.

The front fork has a general design that is more recent, so it could be an aluminium or carbon fibre fork from 2000 onward.  It is definitely a threadless steerer and threadless stem.

---

IMDB confirms that

> The film is set in New York, but was actually filmed in Ireland.

So there's an increased chance its an **Irish** brand, or at least European.

Comment: To narrow it down, the frame has rear facing dropouts. No road frame has these, because they make wheel removal much more difficult than forward facing ones, especially when there is a derailleur. The brake mounts on the other hand rule out serious track frames. My guess would be one of the ubiquitous readymade fixies of 2010s. The reason for full length cable housing is that when you remove rear brake and the clamps, the result looks cleaner than unused cable stops.

Comment: @ojs good spotting - I missed the dropouts being track-ends so its  a permanent one-speed bike.

Answer (score 1):

The frame looks very much like a generic Chinese singer speed frame. They are sold by countless brands.

I have a very similar bike which was sold as Leader, I think (I bought used). I replaced the rubbish brakes and finishing kit.

[image: photo of single speed bike]

The sticker with the brand on the down tube is above the clear coat and peels off. It's quite flimsy. That indicates that the brands are an afterthought by the local distributors.

However, I suspect the bike in the original question was not made for the European market. There are no braze ons for the rear brake cable. It is attached with pipe- or p-clamps. Three finishing kit is probably custom added for the film.

Comment: Any sources for "not made for the European market"?

Comment: It is a conjecture. I've change the answer. Largest market in EU require two independent brakes. Flip-flop hub doesn't provide rear brake with free wheel. The film bike has rear brake jury rigged. No brace ons, silver caliper rear instead of black front.

Comment: Interesting. To me it looks like brakes are both black, and the silver part is barrel adjuster and cable. As already commented on other answer, he reason for full length cable housing is that when you remove rear brake and the clamps, the result looks cleaner than unused cable stops. I don't know what you mean by "board" or "brace ons", perhaps turning off autocorrect would help.

Comment: @ojs autocomplete isn't to blame for I mistyped. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braze-on
However, I do indeed often write from mobile devices. And I do often don't catch when autocomplete does match the wrong word. In both cases sorry.

Comment: I cannot follow you with your argument @ojs. Of course it would look cleaner when there were no awful clamps. But with proper brake cable routing there wouldn't be a need to remove it in the first place to make it look clean. There's hardly anything that looks more like a botched DIY than p-clamps. On the other hand, I do not need to overstretch and assumption. If it bothers you edit out. If it interests you share your findings. :-)